# Method being run through twice when it should only run once

Tags: c#

```
class Myclass
{
    public string Driver1()
    {
        string a = "";

        Console.Write("Please enter drivers name: ");
        a = Console.ReadLine();

        return a;
    }  
    public int numberOfTrips()
    {
        int a = 0;
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of trips: ");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        return a;
    }   
    public List<float> Payments()
    {
        List<float> a = new List<float>();
        float input;

        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfTrips(); i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter payment {0}: ", (1 + i));
            input = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Payment added");
            a.Add(input);
        }

        return a;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Myclass a = new Myclass();

        string name = a.Driver1();
        int trip = a.numberOfTrips();
        float total = a.Payments().Sum();

        Console.WriteLine("\nDriver: {0}\n" + "Number of trips: {1}\n" + "Total payment: {2}\n", name, trip, total);
    }
}
```

The issue i am having is that the "public int numberOfTrips()" method is running twice before it gets to the method containing the for loop. I think this is to do with the fact i am using it within the for loop to specify when the loop should stop. I am guessing i have done this wrong so how would i correct this? I need the user to be able to set the how many times it will ask for payment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the number from `numberOfTrips` as a parameter to `Payments`:

```
public List<float> Payments(int tripCount)
{
    List<float> a = new List<float>();
    float input;

    for (int i = 0; i < tripCount; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter payment {0}: ", (1 + i));
        input = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Payment added");
        a.Add(input);
    }

    return a;
}
```

In your `Main` method:

```
Myclass a = new Myclass();

string name = a.Driver1();
int trip = a.numberOfTrips();
float total = a.Payments(trip).Sum();
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it has worked, thank you :) I am quite new this C#, only been learning for a few days so would you be able to tell me what  the (int tripcount) does and how numberOfTrips passes over to the tripcount. Also, why do i have to use (trip) here:  float total = a.Payments(trip).Sum();

Comment: @CharlieWalkden You are getting the variable from the first time you call `numberOfTrips` and storing it into the variable `trip`. Then you pass the variable as a parameter to `Payments`, which basically gives that method access to that variable so it can use it. (For a more in-depth explanation, look up a tutorial on methods and parameters.)

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling numberOfTrips() in Main() as well as in Payments() you might try creating an instance variable or static variable in MyClass. Then you can fetch the number of trips from that variable after all payments are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.  The first time it runs is in Main to set the 'trip' variable.  The second time it runs is in Payments, inside the for loop declaration.